Follow Symbolic Link To Portable Thumbdrive In Apache
There are quite a few symbolic link questions on stack exchange but couldn't quite find something similar. If I missed please point it out.
So I have Apache2 installed on a 22.04 minimal Xubuntu PC. It's working fine sharing a folder but then I wanted to share files on a thumbdrive mounted at /dev/sda1, I created a symbolic link in the /var/www folder:
sudo ln -s /media/myusername/ESD-ISO thumbdrive

I also changed the owner to www-data:www-data
but get an error message 403 Forbidden when I visit an html file on the thumbdrive.
Any tips, tricks or references would be greatly appreciated!

Does this answer your question? "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible" / Apache on CentOS 6

@ChrisDavies thanks so far I couldn't find the magic there and I think maybe it's related to my thumbdrive formatted as NTFS since it needs to be accessible by windows but not sure.

You're using a symbolic link to somewhere that Apache isn't configured to access. Just like in the other question
